# help finding a book concerning cigarettes addicting alien civilization

Tags: story-identification, novel

Decades ago I read a book in which the plot revolved around a horribly addictive drug in an alien civilization. I think the drug was used by a ruling conglomerate to control citizens. Once they were hooked it was a lifetime addiction, and the conglomerate was the only place the drug could be obtained. The plot twist showed the drug the aliens were hooked on were Earth cigarettes smuggled off planet by alien drug smugglers.

Does anyone know the book and author?

Comment: Possible dupe of [Book with alien POV](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/105837/book-with-alien-pov/105853) and [Sci-Fi Book Ice Planet or something?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/66539/sci-fi-book-ice-planet-or-something).

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction and Fantasy SE. Take a look at [this](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) guide to help jog your memory and [edit](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/152280/edit) any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where? Also, take a look at our [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: @Edlothiad - The [agreed policy](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7065/closing-story-ident-questions-as-duplicates-where-theres-no-acceptance) is that we don't close story-ID questions as duplicates **unless there's a positive confirmation from the OP that they're talking about the same property** (i.e. through a comment or an acceptance of an answer).

Comment: @Valorum, yes sorry I'd forgotten. Retracted my vote. Does that mean someone should just post the answer, or wait for jaye501 to comment?

Comment: @Edlothiad - Either is fine. If you want some free rep, copy the [book blurb](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1875499.Iceworld) off of Goodreads.

Comment: thank you so much... the book is "ice world" by hal clement.... i am so grateful... another note... i'm just curious... this forum allows users to edit the posts of other users??

Comment: @jaye501 this isn't quite a forum but more a Q&A site. Secondly yes. Users that have given significant commitment are able to edit other users' posts without review, however those below 2000 reputation need to have their edits reviewed by more experienced users before the edit taking effect

Comment: @Edlothiad I reviewed your edit and uncapitalized cigarettes. :-)

Comment: @jaye501 An answer to your question has been posted. Please let us know if this is the one you're looking for or not. If it's the right answer, there's no need to post a comment, you can simply "accept" the answer by clicking on the check mark next to it. If it's a wrong answer, please try to remember more detail about your story.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like it could be the 1953 Hal Clement novel [Iceworld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iceworld).

Below is an excerpt:

> The novel concerns an interplanetary narcotics agent who is forced to work on an incredibly cold world (from his point of view — the planet is in fact Earth), where he teams up with natives of the alien planet (humans) in his attempt to stop the ***smuggling of a dangerous drug (tobacco) to Sirius***. Although the story involves both aliens and humans, it is told primarily from an alien perspective.

From my copy I confirmed it lists the tobacco as incredibly addictive. In fact one airborne exposure was enough to cause it in the aliens. Another site lists it as [Fantastic Fiction](https://www.fantasticfiction.com/c/hal-clement/iceworld.htm):

> As the planet gleamed in his viewport, Sallman Ken could not believe that such a bleak and icy globe could have produced intelligent life. Yet when the expedition had sent in unmanned landers, that was what it had found. Some sort of native alien, surviving on the barren planet. But Sallman and his team were not the first to make contact. Smugglers from his own planet had begun trading with the natives for a new and virulent narcotic - the most dangerous drug in the universe. Now Sallman would have to find out how he could survive on a planet so cold that sulphur was solid and water was liquid - and how to stop the source of the deadly drug!

Picture of book cover is:

[image: Book cover]